# Does an inherited class realize the interface the class's parent already realized in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

Let's see. I have to make a homework with a complicated UML diagramm. I have an interface called Q, and a class called W, which realizes the Q interface. I have another class called R, which extends from W.

The question is: Does the class R realize the Q interface?

Thank you guys!

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "realize the Q interface"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do subclasses inherit interfaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534726/do-subclasses-inherit-interfaces)

Comment: public class W implements Q { . . . }

Comment: @user3086500 The proper vocabulary is "W implements Q" and "R extends W".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an interface `Q`

```
interface Q {
  void say();
}
```

and a class `W` which implements `Q`,

```
class W implements Q {
  public void say() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
}
```

and a class `R` which extends `W`

```
class R extends W {
}
```

Then yes, `R` also implements `Q`. You could potentially say,

```
Q q = new R();
q.say();
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Implementing an interface (Q) is a contract stating that your class contains certain methods. 
2) When you make a subclass (R), all methods from the super class (W) are inherited by the subclass.
3) So..what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking: "Does each subclass have to re-implement the interface?" the answer is no. If the superclass implements the interface, the only reason to re-implement it in a subclass is if you need the subclass to do it differently than the superclass.