# Do subclasses need to implement Cloneable?

Tags: java, interface, clone, cloneable

Do subclasses of a class which implements `Cloneable` need also implement it explicitly?

I read some discussions about this ([Do subclasses inherit interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534726/do-subclasses-inherit-interfaces)) but the answers are not very clear.

Answer (score 2):

**No**. Subclasses will *inherit* interfaces that their superclasses implement, and thus ***implicitly*** also implement the interface.  However, it is arguably a better practice to explicitly enumerate the interfaces any given class implements.

See also [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)